# ToString conversion in the C# LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I am having (most likely a trivial problem) with the strings comparison in C#

I am running this LINQ query

```
var result = from q in Table
             where q.ValueDate.ToString() == "12/11/2014 12:00:00 AM"
             select q;
```

and get an empty response

However, when I try

```
foreach (var i in Table)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.ValueDate.ToString());
}
```

I get

```
12/11/2014 12:00:00 AM
12/11/2014 12:00:00 AM
12/11/2014 12:00:00 AM
12/11/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Rather than comparing the `ToString()` output of a `DateTime` property to another date string, parse your date string into a  `DateTime` and do a `DateTime` comparison.

Comment: @BenRobinson [comments are not for answers](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1866). Your comment could easily have been an answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't sacrifice the type safety of a Date by converting it to a string - what is possibly happening is that the `ToString()` is being converted to a *Char type via `CAST` / `CONVERT` in the DB, which results in a different format. Here's how I would do it:

```
var checkDateTime = new DateTime(2014, 11, 12);
var result = from q in Table
          where q.ValueDate == checkDateTime
          select q;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime` object instead of doing string Comparisons:

```
DateTime filter = new DateTime(2014,12,11);
var result = from q in Table
              where q.ValueDate == filter)
              select q
```

or try specifying your date format:

```
var result = from q in Table
              where q.ValueDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") == "12/11/2014 12:00:00 AM"
              select q;
```

[See Attached Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HbENFP)

Comment: No need ToString() anymore?